# Creating a dictionary from a dataframe having duplicate column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 having more than 500k records:

```
state          lat-long
Florida        (12.34,34.12)
texas          (13.45,56.0)
Ohio           (-15,49) 
Florida        (12.04,34.22)
texas          (13.35,56.40)
Ohio           (-15.79,49.34) 
Florida        (12.8764,34.2312)
```

the lat-long value can differ for a particular state.

Need to get a dictonary like below. the lat-long value can differ for a particular state but need to capture the first occurrence like this.

```
dict_state_lat_long = {"Florida":"(12.34,34.12)","texas":"(13.45,56.0)","Ohio":"(-15,49)"}
```

How can I get this in most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe with respect to the states and then you can apply the aggregate function `first` to select the first occurring values of `lat-long` in the grouped dataframe.

Then you can use [`DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) function to convert the dataframe to the python `dict`.

**Use this:**

```
grouped = df.groupby("state")["lat-long"].agg("first")
dict_state_lat_long = grouped.to_dict()
print(dict_state_lat_long)
```

**Output**:

```
{'Florida': '(12.34,34.12)', 'Ohio': '(-15,49)', 'texas': '(13.45,56.0)'}
```

Comment: than you @Shubham

Comment: @PPARI1 if this answered your question you may accept it.